# Re-enable SSL validation in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, ssl, httpsurlconnection

In my Android app (which is a test app) I execute the below disableSslValidation method to disable SSL certificate validation. Now without restarting the process I want to enable SSL certificate validation. How do I accomplish that?

**EDIT:** I am fully aware of the risks involved with disabling SSL validation and knowingly accept said risks.

```
private void disableSslValidation() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
    } };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
}
```

Comment: Partial solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112084/enable-ssl-certificate-validation-jvm/32112192

Answer (score 0):

As this is test code I would suggest you just throw it away. You don't want insecure code leaking into production. You don't even want it present in the application.

Comment: Allow me to disagree as the script can save the production environment **if run with right race conditions**, when the production server has SSL problems. (When programmers have to make it work collaborating with bad sysadmin). Moreover you do not answer the question.