# Enable SSL certificate validation JVM

Tags: java, ssl

The question is very simple.
How to re-enable SSL certificate validation once the following code is executed ?

```
// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
    new X509TrustManager() {     
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        } 
        public void checkClientTrusted( 
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            } 
        public void checkServerTrusted( 
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    } 
}; 

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom()); 
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
}
```

Comment: Don't use this code at all. It isn't a solution to anything. Only a bandaid over an amputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
    sc.init(null, null, null); 
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
}
```

If a parameter of the `init` method is `null`, the default implementation is used.